# How to share the same partition with child window opened by native `window.open` in electron?

Tags: electron

I can pass different `webPreferences.partition` to `BrowserWindow`, but it seems that child window
opened by native `window.open` does not share the same partition with its parent.

So .. How to share the same partition amoung multiple sub windows opened by native `window.open` and thire parent in Electron?

Answer (score 0):

Add an open window handler to your parent window and set the partition:

```js
parentWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  return {
    action: 'allow',
    overrideBrowserWindowOptions: { // Set the new BrowserWindow options
      webPreferences: {
        partition: '' // Your partition
      }
    }
  }
}
```